# "zu" that doesn't cover both verbs in a sentence

Tags: verb

In my German essay I intended to say that Sunday should be a day for relaxing and *another verb in my language that is translated as "relaxing", too*.

I wrote:

> Ein Sonntag sollte einen Tag für relaxieren (relaxen?) und sich zu ausruhen sein.

If you ignore the fact that *relaxieren* and *sich ausruhen* have the same meaning, this sentence sounds correct to me. I connected *sollte* and *sein* at the end, *zu* stands between *sich* and *ausruhen* because I feel that the modal *sollte* is kinda forgotten at this point and *für* covered the verb *relaxieren* to express some sort of intention.

My question is: Does this sentence sounds good to you, even though the *zu* part refers only to *ausruhen* and not *relaxieren*?

Is *ausruhen* trennbar? Should it be *sich auszuruhen* instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ein Sonntag sollte einen Tag für relaxieren (relaxen?) und sich zu ausruhen sein.

There are several problems with your sentence:

---

Two nouns are connected by the verb *sein*; here, both nouns should be in the nominative case, because *sein* uses a so-called *Gleichsetzungsnominativ* (*equalisation nominative*):

> Ein Sonntag *(subject, nominative)* sollte **ein Tag** *(object, nominative)* ... sein.

---

The verb *relaxieren* does exist; however, it is used primarily in a scientific context. For example, it can be an adequate verb for relaxing muscles. It is not used in a context describing people who relieve stress. In colloquial speech you can use the German verb *relaxen* (English pronunciation + German *-en*). A more formal word would be *sich entspannen*.

---

You can use different constructions to express what Sunday should be a day for:

- *zum X-en:* Ein Sonntag sollte ein Tag **zum Entspannen und (zum) Ausruhen** sein.
- *um + zu:* Ein Sonntag sollte ein Tag sein, **um sich zu entspannen und (um) sich auszuruhen.**
- *für das X-en:* Ein Sonntag sollte ein Tag **fürs Entspannen und (fürs) Ausruhen** sein.
- ...

As you can see, if you choose the *zu* variant, there should be a *zu* attached to both infinitives. I'm quite sure there are more valid possibilities to form a correct sentence.

---

As you have guessed, *sich ausruhen* is a separable verb (*ich ruhe mich aus*, not *ich ausruhe mich*) and thus, the *zu + infinitive* form should be *sich auszuruhen*.

---

Whether you use *Ein Sonntag* or *Der Sonntag* or *Sonntag* is a matter of taste and conveys different degrees of definiteness; I don't want to go too much in detail as this could be worth another question.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is:

```
Sonntag sollte ein Tag zum Entspannen und Ausruhen sein.
```

- you wouldn't necessarily say "Ein Sonntag" but just "Sonntag" when referring to this day in general.
- to relax in German is also "entspannen"
- I changed the structure to make it grammatically correct

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd go with the definite article; or none at all.
2. *Relaxieren* does not exist. It's *relaxen*.
3. *Für* is not the proper preposition here, but *zum*.
4. You don't need the reflexive *sich*. You can add it, though.
5. After the preposition *zum* (and *für* for that matter), the verb 'functions' as substantive. *Zu*, however, is part of the infinitive, so you need to drop it.
6. When using *sein* it's like the *=* sign in mathematics. In a sentence both parts must be in the same grammatical case when connected with *to be*.

> Der Sonntag sollte ein Tag zum Relaxen und (sich) Ausruhen sein.

You can rephrase the sentence a bit and use *um*, followed by an infinitive clause. Or a relative clause, with the indefinite pronoun "man". Then, of course, you need to conjugate the verbs (third person).

> Der Sonntag sollte ein Tag sein, um zu relaxen und sich auszuruhen.
>   Der Sonntag sollte ein Tag sein, an dem man relaxt und sich ausruht.

Comment: _relaxieren_ does exist but isn't used in this context.

Comment: @Chris Didn't know that word and any reliable sources do not list it either. I checked that before posting; I just read your answer afterwards. I'm sure you're right on that, but I'm not going to change my statement. It's unlikely that a native speaker will ever hear that word, let alone a language learner. So, there's nothing wrong with pretending this word doesn't exist at all.

Comment: I haven't found it in a dictionary either; however I have heard it several times in scientific (anatomical) context and there are some google hits for "Darm relaxiert" or "Muskulatur relaxiert". But very sparse; okay, let's pretend it didn't exist^^ :-)